# Gridview in Android, with dynamic width & height of blocks

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a Gridview just like a GooglePlay. The only difference in our case is the size of width & height should be the based on the popularity.

For example, If I have a array list of categories along with number of popularity. The order of category is fixed, so it will appear on the grid in same order, the only thing is going to change its width and height.

So, If my grid has 2 columns, then blocks should be adjusted automatically.

I have seen the demo of stagerred view but unable to replicate as per my requirement. So If any one has any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the width of your block automatically you have to get Display Size.

This code Works for me.

```
public static void calculateSize(Activity ac) {
    DisplayMetrics dMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ac.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dMetrics);
    float density = dMetrics.density;
    int w = Math.round(dMetrics.widthPixels / density);
    int h = Math.round(dMetrics.heightPixels / density);
    YourBlock.WIDTH = Math.round((w - (YourBlock.PADDING * (YourBlock.COLUMN + 1))) / YourBlock.COLUMN);
    YourBlock.HEIGHT = Math.round(YourBlock.WIDTH * YourBlock.RATIO);
}
```

In this case:

```
    public static final int YouBlock.COLUMN = 2;
    public static float YourBlock.RATIO = 2.0f/3;
    public static int YouBlock.PADDING = 4;
```

Example:

[image]
Each item will automacticaly adjusts width with each device (each size)